# How to add a second condition to this equal statement?

Tags: php, equals

I am using this snippet below, how can i add a second equal statement with an "and" so something like ($onevariable === $othervariable) and ($2variable ===$2othervariable)

```
  if ( $onevariable === $othervariable ) {
  require("file.php");
  }
```

Comment: This is fairly basic, please see [Logical Operators (PHP)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). It's just how you already wrote in your question: `if ( ($onevariable === $othervariable) and ($2variable ===$2othervariable) )` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straight-forward, it's just how you already wrote in your question:

```
if ( ($onevariable === $othervariable) and ($2variable === $2othervariable) ) {
    require("file.php");
}
```

See as well [Logical Operators (PHP)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

**Note:** `$2variable` is not a valid variable name, as well isn't `$2othervariable` because they start with a number. But I think you get the idea from the example code.

Comment: yup just realized that, i was thinking in theory so just used random examples.

Comment: Thought so as well, the note was just a pre-caution, that's all ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do this with `&&`

```
if ( $onevariable === $othervariable && $2variable === $2othervariable) {
```

You can read more about [logical operators here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can Directly use the && operator like this

```
if ( $onevariable === $othervariable && $2variable ===$2othervariable )
{
  require("file.php");
}
```

further You can visit [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the logical and operator `&&`. You can also use `and` if you prefer, but `&&` is more in use. The only difference between the two is [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

```
if ($onevariable === $othervariable && $2variable === $2othervariable) {
    require("file.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [`&&` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php):

```
if ( $onevariable === $othervariable && $2variable === $2othervariable ) {
  require("file.php");
}
```